# Azure DevOps – automated test cases: How to remove unwanted test case associations

Tags: testing, case

I have a Visual Studio project with a Selenium test. For the test, I can select the “Associate to Test Case” option, but this displays a list of test case associations and it seems that I can only add test cases to this list. If I decide to replace the associated test case with another one, how can I remove from the list the one that I no longer want to be associated?

I created a new Visual Studio project with the test by copying a similar project that I had made previously, and I obtained a new project with an old test case associated. Why did this happen? What do I need to do differently to prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

On Azure DevOps, find the unwanted Testcase you want to remove from the association.
Go to the tab "Associated Automation" and click on the "Clear" button.
Once you do this, your test case will be removed from the list of associated test cases inside VS.

Here is a picture of where you can find this button

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Turbo. This works. The text of the “Clear” button is almost unreadable in the dark mode. This is why I did not notice the button.